# User Defined Function in Conditional formatting Excel VBA

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

I have the following User defined function in the conditional formatting formula criteria:

```
=hasTrigger()
```

And this is the actual function:

```
Function hasTrigger() as variant
Dim rngCaller As Range

Set rngCaller = Application.Caller

If rngCaller.Value="A" then hasTrigger=1

End Function
```

Moreover, I have an addin that forces calculations to update every second.

So, although the calculations are updated every second, when I set the value of the cell in which I have applied this conditional formatting equal to "A", the conditional formatting changes are not applied.

Does anyone know why?

Update: I closed and reopened excel and now many cells look like they have lost their values or colors. If I scroll the screen and come back, then they appear again.

[image: Cells A1, B1 etc have values but not shown.]

Cells A1, B1 etc have values but not shown.

Regards

Thanasis

Comment: I don't know the answer, but perhaps adding `Application.Volatile` at the top of the function definition might help. Also -- that seems to be setting up a weird circular reference. The semantics of circular references in Excel have always been a bit murky.

Comment: Already did it but no luck. The weird thing is that when I do a change in the function's code, then the conditional formatting changes are applied to the cells.

Comment: Rather than a circular UDF with once a second calculation, why not use a `Worksheet_Change` event handler which targets the cells which currently contain that formula?

Comment: without the add-in, it works perfectly for me in XL 2010. When the cell is either hard-changed or changed via formula reference to another cell.

Comment: Instead of getting the cell by the caller, pass the cell address in as a criteria.  Then point to the upper left cell of the applied to range.

Comment: You are correct @ScottHoltzman. I also tested in another instance of excel and it works fine.

@JohnColeman I want to have the code dynamic and not assign which cells I want in the `Worksheet_Change` event

Comment: So I guess it has to do with the add-in that re-calculates the workbook all the time. But I have other conditional formatting running on Excel functions and they work fine.

Comment: @ScottCraner The fact that the code works on a workbook without the other add-in running at the back, I think this won't solve the problem.

Comment: Won't know unless you try. :)

Comment: @ScottCraner Unfortunately, I did it and still not applying the conditional formatting.

Comment: This is getting a little old now but I was having similar issues with Excel aabout the same time and was able to resolve by updating the graphics drivers and reinstalling Office. It could well be there were no issues at all with the code.
I do also back up other users suggestion to using a Worksheet_Change event and target the updates required instead of recalculating everything, every second.